# Mousetrap firing twice

Tags: javascript, mousetrap

This is my code:

```
Mousetrap.bind('l', (e) => {
  console.log('l')
})

Mousetrap.bind('k+l', (e) => {
  console.log('k+l')
})
```

I have 2 questions:

**1.** When I press `l` I'm seeing both logs. Any ideas why?

**2.** When I'm pressing `k + l`, I'm seeing both logs too (I understand why) but any ideas how to prevent this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because **`k` is not a valid modifier key**.

As described in [the docs](https://craig.is/killing/mice):

> For modifier keys you can use shift, ctrl, alt, or meta.

In other words, `k+l` is normalized to `l`, i.e. you are binding `l` twice.

---

For more details, you can check out the relevant bit of logic [in the mousetrap source directly](https://github.com/ccampbell/mousetrap/blob/825ce50c64cc2d9aaaddb453e6dc417aa64fdbbb/mousetrap.js#L380).